# Numpy array vs. class for storing data when scientific simulation?

Tags: python, numpy, class, simulation

So, I am doing some scientific simulation using python. I'm having trouble deciding whether I should use numpy array or class to store my data. Here are an example.

```
class C():
    def __init__(delf, a, b):
        self.a = a # scalar
        self.b = b # vector of n items
```

```
import numpy as np
c = np.array([a, b[0], ... , b[n]])
```

I want to know whether any of the two options have any advantages that I should stick with. Or both of them have some advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: what kind of simulation are you doing? you can also use the numpy array in a class.... In the numpy array it look like you are merging a and b into one array, but in the class you are not? which one is required by the simulation?  It all really depends what your goal is. If you can't answer it, I suggest forgetting about classes to begin with, and see where that goes.

Comment: Don't mix data types in an array unnecessarily.  `c` doesn't do you any good if you end up using `c[0]` and `c[1:]` to get at `a` and `b`, and never use the whole `c`.

Comment: What is the class supposed to represent?  How many instanced of this class will you  use?  A class that represents the whole problem space with a collection of arrays makes good use of `numpy` code.  A class that represents 'points' with small parameter (coordinate) arrays does not.  An array containing many 'points' does not do math efficiently.

Comment: @Gerges `a` and `b` stand for different meaning, but they are all numbers. I merge them to c, because this way I can only use one array. This may sound stupid, but I am new, I thought this is concise. However, in the class, I use different attribute for different data with different meaning.

Comment: @hpaulj I have many instances of a class, if I use class. So, I thought that use only one array may be better.